# Rspec check if a method has been called without calling the method

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am pretty new with RSpec an althought I have been reading a lot about how to check if a method has been called I cannot find a proper solution for the case I need. Sorry if this is a duplicate but couldn't find anything :S

I have an object which implements this function

```
def link
  paths.each do |old,new|
    FileUtils.ln_s old, new
  end
end
```

Several links are done based on paths (which is a hash pairing old and new files). My test for this looks like this:

```
context "linking files to new ones" do
  it "links a sample to the propper file" do
    @comb.link
    expect(FileUtils).to have_received(:ln_s).with("/example/path/files/old.root",
                                             "example/path/nornmfiles/new.root")
  end
end
```

Since I want to test that at least on of them has been called  have to use the `have_received` method since the receive ones will fail as soon as the `ln_s` method gets called with different arguments. The issue is that the test fails because this is a test and I an mot going to actually create the links because the files don't exists so it fails raising an exception because the files don't exists.

How can I test this without actually having to call the method?

**This call also fail as soon as a different call is made**

```
  it "links a sample with a region subpath to the propper file" do
    expect(FileUtils).to receive(:ln_s).with("/example/path/files/pathsuff/old.root",
                                             "/example/path/normfiles/pathsuff/new.root").at_least(:once)
    @comb.link
  end
```

It gives this error:

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: FileUtils received :ln_s with unexpected 
arguments
   expected: ("/example/path/files/pathsuff/old.root", 
 "/example/path/normfiles/pathsuff/new.root")
   got: ("/example/path/files/old.root", 
 "/example/path/normfiles/new.root")
```

which is on of the other calls with different methods that can happen that can be called

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
context "linking files to new ones" do
  it "links a sample to the propper file" do
    allow(FileUtils).to receive(:ln_s)

    @comb.link

    expect(FileUtils).to have_received(:ln_s).with(
      "/example/path/files/old.root",
      "example/path/nornmfiles/new.root",
    ).at_least(:once)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I alrady tried that and it always fails when a different call is made, that is why I assumed that I had to use the `have_received` method. I am editting the question

Comment: This works prfectly! What does the `stub` method do exactly? What I have read about stub has been a bit cryptic

Comment: @JuanpeAraque, what stub does is basically replace the method with a dummy implementation. In this case calling `FileUtils.ln_s` after the stub will simply return `nil` without doing anything else.

Comment: Great thanks! Mayb you want to update the answer since it prints a deprecation error. It seems that the proper syntax is `allow(FileUtlis).to recieve(:ln_s)`

Comment: @ndn the deprecation warning is for `#stub` as 3.X has replaced this with the `allow().to receive` syntax. [New Syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/basics/allowing-messages) [Old Syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/old-syntax)

Comment: @engineersmnky updated, thanks. I'm still living in the past.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about actual arguments (but rather simple number of calls)

```
expect(FileUtils).to receive(:ln_s).with(anything, anything).exactly(paths.length).times
@comb.link
```

If you do care about arguments

```
expect(FileUtils).to receive(:ln_s).with('foo', 'bar').ordered
expect(FileUtils).to receive(:ln_s).with('foo2', 'bar2').ordered
expect(FileUtils).to receive(:ln_s).with('foo3', 'bar3').ordered
@comb.link
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue with this is that the amount of calls is pretty big to put all checks on by one and  actually want to test that all have been called with different properties in different examples, @ndn answers works perfects